# I want to make a timer counting down in the background of my code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a game in py2.7 and I want to know how to create a timer running in the background of my code and when time is up, a command is executed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We're gonna need more details than that. Ex: are you using PyGame? Tkinter? Is it a console game?

Comment: @RobertR nope just plain python 2.7 - will implement tkinter later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer). The [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module might also be useful.

Comment: I have tried to implement threading timer with this code:     import threading
import random
mamount = int('2')
fgw = int('0')
fgo = int('0')
growtime = random.randint(90, 180)
def mfullygrown():
    print("one of your Marijuana plants grew to full height! You have", mamount ,"plants still growing")

t = Timer(growtime, mfullygrown)
t.start()
but I still get an error

Comment: Nope! I got it, I had a problem with the import.

Comment: You should be using a tool that makes it easier to see that you have a problem with your imports. I recommend PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using for the game you will need to refresh the output so it doesn't print line by line, but this is a simple way to count down from 60 seonds:

```
from time import sleep

time = 60

while time != 0:
    print time
    time -= 1
    sleep(1)
```